# Passing PHP variable in a javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<button class="addToPlaylist" onclick="javascript:myPopup(<?php echo $videos[$counter]?>);
return false;">+</button>
```

I have a button on an image as a html hyperlink. I want to perform different actions on hyperlink and button. The above code works whenever I do not pass the PHP variable using echo. When i pass PHP variable, the button also performs the same action as of the hyperlink, that means return false does not work.

Any idea why the return false; does not work when i pass PHP variable?

Comment: Check the HTML source, see what PHP has generated.

Comment: Is `$videos[$counter]` a string?  If so, you need quotes around it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be:

```
<button class="addToPlaylist" onclick="javascript:myPopup('<?php echo $videos[$counter];?>');return false;">+</button>
```

Note the single quotes in myPopup. As you pass a string to myPopup, you will need to enclose it with single quotes. (Double won't work as there is already double quotes for the onclick)

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure $videos[$counter] is not numeric, but a string. In this case you have to write the quotes:

```
onclick="javascript:myPopup('<?php echo $videos[$counter]?>');
```

And make sure, $videos[$counter] doesn't contain any, something like

```
onclick="javascript:myPopup('<?php echo addslashes($videos[$counter])?>');
```

comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

onclick="javascript:myPopup("";return false;" . This should work and i think it's more clear where you have javascript code and php code.